# 42809: (timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) is a procedure POSITION: 15

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

C# Application
Project Entityframework 4.7.2
Npgsql version 7.0.1

I have provided below the C# code and PostgresSQL Schema. When the code executes the cmd, it failed with 42809: red.common$getreinsurers(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) is a procedure POSITION: 15. I don't know why it is not bringing back the "SELECT" records from the schema procedure. Don't understand position 15?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM red.common$getreinsurers(@p_fromdate,@p_todate)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_fromdate", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, dateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_todate", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, dateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_refcursorreinsurers", NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
                    cmd.Parameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_sqlcode", NpgsqlDbType.Double);
                    cmd.Parameters[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_sqlerrm", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
```

Schema

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE red.common$getreinsurers(IN p_fromdate timestamp without time zone, IN p_todate timestamp without time zone, OUT p_refcursorreinsurers refcursor, 
AS 
$BODY$timestamp without time zone, IN p_todate timestamp without time zone, OUT p_refcursorreinsurers refcursor, 
DECLARE
    p_refCursorReinsurers$ATTRIBUTES aws_oracle_data.TCursorAttributes;
BEGIN
    p_refCursorReinsurers := NULL;
    OPEN p_refCursorReinsurers FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        r.*, tg.name AS tg_name, tg.id AS treaty_group_id, tg.start_date AS tg_start_date, tg.minimum_incident_date AS tg_minimum_incident_date, tg.maximum_incident_date AS tg_maximum_incident_date, tgr.percentage_repayment, tgr.effective_from_date, tgr.effective_to_date
        FROM red.treaty_groups AS tg, red.treaty_group_reinsurers AS tgr, red.reinsurers AS r
        WHERE tg.id = tgr.treaty_group_id AND tgr.reinsurers_id = r.id AND tgr.effective_from_date <= p_fromdate AND tgr.effective_to_date >= p_todate;
    p_refCursorReinsurers$ATTRIBUTES := ROW (TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    p_sqlcode := '';
    p_sqlerrm := '';
END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: Hi! This question is pretty hard to understand, but you can make it easier if you explain what you're trying to do with this code. Can you edit your post?

Comment: Your specification of the procedure is garbled.  It has unbalanced parenthesis, lacks a LANGUAGE specification, and maybe has some random bits of the signature copied from one place and pasted into another.

Comment: You cannot `SELECT` from a procedure, you can only `CALL` it. Procedures have no return value.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

1. DateTime.Now uses time zone, without time zone you need to use DateTime.UtcNow.
2. Or in the procedure change the input parameters to timestamp with time zone instead of without time zone (and in this case save DateTime.Now) if a time zone is needed

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried it with DateTime.UtcNow, I got another error, Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array, range, or multirange.
Parameter name: value.

Comment: You need to understand date types. Apparently, somewhere 'timestamp with time zone' is used, and somewhere 'timestamp without time zone'. Or bring everything to a single style - if without time zone, then use DateTime.UtcNow. If with time zone, use DateTime.Now. So there should be no mixing of types within the functions themselves. If a function has an input parameter 'timestamp with time zone', which is inserted into a table with the type 'timestamp with zone', then an error will also occur; it must be converted to the same style.